# How to implement Time varying EWMA cross correlation in STATA?

Tags: time-series, statistical-finance

I have read [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18707/estimating-correlation-using-ewma), I know about lambda, demeaned subindexes. But not able to implement in STATA?